# White gap and break in Apple-style CSS spritesheet menu

Tags: html, css, layout

Please see http://shivimpanim.org/testsite/

It is very simple css, and my goal is to essentially duplicate Apple's menubar

Strangely- I'm getting a white gap between several of the buttons, and the last button is breaking onto the next line!

For right now, I've eliminated the dividers in the graphic to be sure that it's definitely an html/css error and not the divider I'm seeing.

Please help :)

Thanks!

Comment: In firefox 5 I don't see a white gap, the search goes to next line because the width of `ul` is `960px` if you change it to `970px` will be inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid I don't see the white gaps you are talking about in Firefox 5 or IE8 (which browser are you using?). However the reason the last `<li>` is dropping to the next line is because your button widths are too wide for the container.

Your `<ul>` is 960px wide, but the sum of your individual `<li>` widths is 970px. So if you reduce a few of your `<li>` items down by a total of 10px it will all fit in.

Comment: I'm using firefox 3.6.19 on Mac OSX

Comment: The gaps are very small- like 1px

Thanks for the info about the li widths! Is there a way on stackoverflow to accept an answer but keep the question open? (I'm new)

Comment: Accepting an answer and closing a question are two different things. When you an accept an answer the question remains active, but tells people that you consider the answer to have solved your problem.

Comment: fixing the size seemed to fix the gap issue too (haven't updated the website since it was just for this test) :)